# Python and Excel Date Update beside the initial output from Program

Tags: python, excel

Python''

This is my initial code and the result only shows in the 1st column. Every time I run the program, the next row will be filled with the result. I am required to add actual date beside the output every time I run the program. A1 - Public IP B1 - DATE and TIME

Or is it possible to have an automatic update or interval ?

from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import os
import requests

workbook = Workbook()

filename = "publicIP.xlsx"

success = "DONE"

if os.path.exists(filename):

```
workbook = load_workbook(filename, read_only=False)
sheet = workbook.active
counter = 1
keep_going = True

while keep_going:
    cell_id = 'A' + str(counter)
    if sheet[cell_id].value is None:
        sheet[cell_id] = requests.get('http://ip.42.pl/raw').text
        keep_going = False
    else:
        counter += 1

workbook.save(filename)
print(success)
```

else:
    # If file does not exist, you have to create an empty file from excel first
    print('Please create an empty file ' + filename + ' from excel, as it throws error when created from openpyxl')

Comment: What is the problem doing `B1 = DATE_and_TIME` ?

Comment: I don't know the code. Please help

Comment: Use [`sheet.append(...`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#write-a-workbook) instead and read about [datetime.datetime.now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now)